# Input file variable?

Tags: powershell

Since the newly deployed Scanning-Software doesn't support a "Scan to print"-function anymore, only a "Scan to Application", I want to script something that handles the scanned files and sends them to the default printer. Using Adobe Acrobat as some kind of bridge would be okay.

While searching for a solution, I found `Start-Process –FilePath “c:\docstoprint\doc1.pdf” –Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$_} | kill`, which would suffice completely.
However, I'd need to know the temporary file name, which I don't. My idea is to change the script so that it would print any pdf which I opened with it, and not just those in a fixed location. How would I handle this?

Comment: You mean you want to find all pdf files in a specific location and pass those files to start-process?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Basically yes. Thing is, I don't know how the Scanner-Software processes the files to send them directly to the printing application. 
Is there even a way to find that out or would I need ro reverse engineer the Software?